# How do I decrease div height progressively while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, parallax

I have a `div` at the top of my page that gets its height from its contents. It's sliding down using jQuery when the page loads. What I want to do is slowly decrease the height of the `div` while scrolling until it reaches 0.  I need to hide the `div` progressively while scrolling like the slideUp function does.

I tried the plugin Scrollorama but I think it's too heavy for such a small feature.

I tried a script from another blog that it does the opposite, but I can't make it work.

I made a fiddle with the exact issue: http://jsfiddle.net/HYPyw/8/

Comment: Please don't link to external pages containing your source-code. Copy a sample of the code to demonstrate the problem into your question. If the link breaks your question will be worthless to people looking for the same question in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was kind of hard to visualize what you are trying to do, but i came up with this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYPyw/19/) from what you were asking. if its not what you were looking for, please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the input McMaster!
It's pretty close. But what i'd like to do is the "hiding" of the div to follow the scrolling and not execute instantly when the scroll event triggers. I guess when scroll position is 0 the div is fully open and when you scroll it progressively follows the scrolling until it closes, if you move up again it opens.

Check the behaviour of the header on this website, i guess it's more complicated because the header is fixed but you can see in action the progressive hiding of the div with scrolling.

http://crane-brothers.com

Comment: i actually gave you the wrong link. my fault. check out this one [http://jsfiddle.net/HYPyw/22/](http://jsfiddle.net/HYPyw/22/)
and to get rid of the scroll bars on the resizing div, set css `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: Great! Exactly! Thanks McMaster!